# Display AD User Password Expiration Dates and Users with already expired passwords in a single list, in a specific OU with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I have this sweet code that shows me password expiration dates, with the number of days until the password expires. It works fine, but in addition to this list, I also want to view accounts that have already expired passwords, because this script shows only active accounts with working passwords.

Is there any chance, to list expired accounts with "0" mark in the "DaysUntilExpired" column in addition to this list ?

```bsh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$MaxPwdAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days
$expiredDate = (Get-Date).addDays(-$MaxPwdAge)

#Set the number of days until you would like to begin notifing the users. -- Do Not Modify --
#Filters for all users who's password is within $date of expiration.
$ExpiredUsers = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=US,OU=Organization,DC=Company,DC=My,DC=com" -Filter {(PasswordLastSet -gt $expiredDate) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false) -and (Enabled -eq $true)} -Properties PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordLastSet, Mail | 
 select samaccountname, PasswordLastSet, @{name = "DaysUntilExpired"; Expression = {$_.PasswordLastSet - $ExpiredDate | select -ExpandProperty Days}} | 
 Sort-Object PasswordLastSet
$ExpiredUsers
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's important to use code blocks so it is easier for other people here to read your code. Have you checked out [Search-ADAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/search-adaccount?view=win10-ps)? There are various options to list disabled, expired and inactive accounts. Look at the examples.

Comment: `Search-ADAccount` is very useful indeed, but I don't think it'll work here.  It looks like he wants to notify based on #days until the password expires.  Interestingly the help document alludes to to a `-PasswordExpiring` parameter, but there is none.  Even still, you'd have to specify a specific date, not a number of days until or a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some simplifications, mostly so I could read your code more easily.  However, if I'm reading your question correctly, you just want to know when an account is already expired.  But, I think the code would already do that by returning a negative number of days.  However, you are filtering for users that are by definition not expired, `(PasswordLastSet -gt $expiredDate)`. Try removing that portion of the filter...

Also, you may want to add a Boolean property like "Expired". If `$DaysUntilExpired -le 0` set it to true otherwise set it to false.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$MaxPwdAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days
$expiredDate = (Get-Date).addDays(-$MaxPwdAge)

$OU     = "OU=US,OU=Organization,DC=Company,DC=My,DC=com"
$Filter = "(PasswordNeverExpires -eq `$false) -and (Enabled -eq `$true)"
$Props  = 'PasswordNeverExpires', 'PasswordLastSet', 'Mail'

#Set the number of days until you would like to begin notifing the users. -- Do Not Modify --
#Filters for all users who's password is within $date of expiration.
$ExpiredUsers = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -Filter $Filter -Properties $Props | 
Select-Object samaccountname, PasswordLastSet, @{name = "DaysUntilExpired"; Expression = { ($_.PasswordLastSet - $ExpiredDate).Days } } | 
Select-Object *,@{Name = 'Expired'; Expression = {If($_.DaysUntilExpired -le 0){$true}Else{$false} }} |
Sort-Object PasswordLastSet
$ExpiredUsers
```

Also, you are retrieving the mail property, but you aren't selecting it. I assume you're going to be emailing the users, so you may want to add it to your `Select-Object` command.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: OMG you are totally right, thank you! Forgot about removing (PasswordLastSet -gt $expiredDate) portion. And thanks for advice about Boolean property, very useful!